# In iptables, what is the difference between targets DNAT and REDIRECT?

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding

More specifically, is

```
-A PREROUTING -i $INT -p $PROTO --dport $PORT -j REDIRECT --to-ports $NEWPORT
```

equivalent to one or both of these?

```
-A PREROUTING -i $INT -p $PROTO --dport $PORT -j DNAT --to-destination :$NEWPORT
-A PREROUTING -i $INT -p $PROTO --dport $PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $IP_OF_INT:$NEWPORT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to netfilter documentation, redirection is a specialized case of destination NAT. `REDIRECT` is equivalent to doing `DNAT` to the incoming interface.

[Linux 2.4 NAT HOWTO -- Destination NAT](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.2)

So it means the first and second strings are equivalent.

```
-A PREROUTING -i $INT -p $PROTO --dport $PORT -j REDIRECT --to-ports $NEWPORT
-A PREROUTING -i $INT -p $PROTO --dport $PORT -j DNAT --to-destination :$NEWPORT
```

The string:

```
-A PREROUTING -i $INT -p $PROTO --dport $PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $IP_OF_INT:$NEWPORT
```

does the same job **only** if `$IP_OF_INT` - is the IP address on the incoming interface (IP of `$INT`).

Comment: That link is very helpful, thank you. Just so that I can be 100% sure for future reference, could you please quote the strings that you mean when you say 'first and second'?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Your edits really cleared things up for me, I feel significantly more sure of what I'm doing now.